# assoc in clojure: explanation of the internals

Tags: clojure, immutability

Here is the code for `assoc`:

```
(def assoc
 (fn assoc
   ([map key val] (. clojure.lang.RT (assoc map key val)))))
```

1. What is the meaning of `clojure.lang.RT`?
2. What is the complexity of calling `assoc` on a vector/map?
3. What is the complexity of accessing a structure that has been created by `assoc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `clojure.lang.RT` is the main Clojure RunTime class. It has most of the methods that make up the core of the language.
2. `assoc` is O(1) for all the associative data structure including vectors and maps. `array-map` starts out linear for the first few item, then promoted itself to a `hash-map` so it is O(1) as well. You could of course implement the associative interface with something that is not O(1) if you need to.
3. Technically the access time for an item in a map or vector that was created by calling `assoc` on another map is O(log32 N). Because these data structures have an upper bound on the size of ~2^32 items this leaves a maximum tree depth of six which **effectively constant time**

Clojure's associative data structures are all O(nLog n) in space (because they are trees).

Comment: I'm trying to understand how `assoc` works on a map when it has to modify an existing entry? Do you know where could I find material on it?

Comment: and this one http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey (specifically 20 min. into it)

Comment: start with the second one I think